# Python + Django vs. ASP.NET + C#/VB vs PHP?

Tags: php, asp.net, python, django

I know similar questions to this have been asked before, but I'm looking for a more specific answer so here it goes:

I'm a student and am looking to develop a web app. I have little experience with all mentioned and like different aspects of each. I like the Visual  Web Dev that can be used to create ASP.NET sites, a aspect that isn't there for PHP or Python..

I'm also looking to learn and develop with the language that will be most beneficial for uni, and work in the future - the language that is used and respected most in industry. I've heard mixed views about this. Because I'd want to know the language that is most used, most in demand, and has the longest future.

I'd also like the ability to make things fast, they all come with frameworks.. But would it be better me learning things from scratch and understanding how it works that use a framework? Which language has the most frameworks and support?

I see that a lot of industries (the ones I've looked at) use ASP.NET. But it *seems* (remember no real experience) to be easier (especially as a GUI can be used) so does that make it less valuable.

Basically - which language do you think would be best for me based on this? WHich would you recommend based on the advantages and disadvantages of each and ease of fast efficient and powerful development?

Thanks

Comment: Nice question - it'll likely be shot down shortly as out of place here on SO - but for my pennies ASP.NET & C# ;-)

Comment: Why would you choose it?

Comment: The "visual" development environment, free and/or heavily discounted student development software and wealth of beginners books and sites will undoubtedly get you going bit if you're interested in a development career there is no disputing (whether you love them or hate them) the powerhouse that Microsoft are in the development world, the vast opportunities and roles this provides but also the mainstream Visual Studio and C# skills can give you a doorway into other non-web areas such as WinForms or WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really too open ended. there is no one true language, otherwise we'd all be using it. As you've seen they all have merit. You didn't mention Java which still holds a lot of clout in enterprise computing.

The only answer is pick one you like and get good at it. You can spends years wishing you'd picked one of the others. Also, if you get good at one & have a firm understanding of the basics, at a later date you'll find it easy (ish) to pick up another one.

For what it's worth. my money's on .net. But that's just me.

Simon

Answer (score 1):

python has a ui like vb, it's called pygtk (pygtk.org), i suggest you learn python, it's the easiest to learn, and you don't have to write as much as you would in .net

php is powerful, and you have to learn it, you just have to, but for big complicated web apps, I rather choose ruby on rails or even better django

which is the best? "the best" is just an opinion, asp.net developers think that it's the best and i think that python is the best, it's an argument that will never end

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend looking at asp.net mvc and scaffolding. That way you can create good applications quick and effective.